# Passing parameters with space to function

Tags: angularjs, html

I was writing a code in html5 and angular js. I am encountering a problem in passing parameters with space. Here is my code :

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      
      $scope.validate = function(description,code) {
        alert(description,code);
      }
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-repeat="x in allItem.items" class="col-75" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <a href="#" ng-click="validate({{x.itemDesc}},{{x.itemCode}})">
   <div class="card item center">{{x.itemName}}
   </div></a>
    </div>
  </body>
    </html>
```

The JSON format is like this
Json contains

```
allItem
  {
    items
        {
          itemName: "egg",
          itemDesc: "Egg is very delicious",
          itemCode: "EGG"
          }

         {
           itemName: "Tomato",
           itemDescr: "Tomato's skin contains vitamins",
           itemCode: "TMT"
           }
    }
```

I am not able to pass the parameters. I don't know how to pass the text that contains spaces and quotes('). Can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json needs to be an array, skip the href="#" and you do not need to bind within ng-click. The code below is fully functioning and running.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {


        $scope.allItem =
        {
            items:[
                {
                    itemName: "egg",
                    itemDesc: "Egg is very delicious",
                    itemCode: "EGG"
                },

                {
                    itemName: "Tomato",
                    itemDesc: "Tomato's skin contains vitamins",
                    itemCode: "TMT"
                }
]
        };


        $scope.validate = function(description, code) {

            console.log(description,'-', code);
        };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <br/>
       
        <div ng-repeat="x in allItem.items" class="col-75">
            <a ng-click="validate(x.itemDesc, x.itemCode)">
                <div class="card item center">{{x.itemName}}
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Enkode . Now my problem is fixed.